# How do I find the full text of a bill from an early 1900s US Congress

Tags: united-states, congress, history, legislation, reference-request

**Summary**

I'm researching a US House Representative by reading the bills he voted on, which are from the early 1900s.  Where can I find the full text of those bills?

**Details**

The Representative I'm researching was part of the 59th through the 62nd US Congresses (March 4, 1905 - March 3, 1913).  A sample bill he voted on was HR28812.  The description of the bill from voteview.com is INDIANA POWDER FACTORY MUST OPERATE AT MAX. CAPACI., and the link to the voteview.com votes is here: https://voteview.com/rollcall/RH0620249

**Things I've tried**

- I've been to congress.gov and typed in the bill number (HR28812), but nothing comes up.
- I also tried looking for bills on C-SPAN >> Congress >> All Bills >> and specifying the 62nd Congress, but no bills come up (link: https://www.c-span.org/congress/bills/?chamber=house)

**Questions**

Here are all my questions:

1. Where can I find the full text of the sample bill and others like it?
2. Where would a paper version of the example bill be stored, or would this kind of bill have likely been thrown away or lost, or would it still be around somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where can I find the full text of the sample bill and others like it?

The Congressional Record "often contains text of measures after passing a Chamber; sometimes before".

The vote was for an amendment to a bill. For the bill in question, begin at [Statutes at Large](https://www.loc.gov/law/help/statutes-at-large/index.php), where for the 62nd Congress, Session 3, Chapter 148, [An Act Making appropriations for the naval service for the fiscal year ending June thirtieth, nineteen hundred and fourteen, and for other purposes.](https://www.loc.gov/law/help/statutes-at-large/62nd-congress/session-3/c62s3ch148.pdf), contains the text of the final bill. The approved text of the amendment is on the page numbered 896.

> Where would a paper version of the example bill be stored, or would this kind of bill have likely been thrown away or lost, or would it still be around somewhere?

See, [Sources for the Text of Congressional Bills and Resolutions](https://www.llsdc.org/sources-for-congressional-bills-resolutions)

---

Most votes are on amendments, so you might learn more by looking at the amendments.

The text of amendments is included in the Congressional Record. Copies of the Congressional Record are on-line, even going back into the 1800s. They are in the form of PDFs. However, finding the right PDF may be more art than science. Fortunately, enough information is available to find this vote and the text of the amendment.

The source of vote was given as "Congressional Record vol. 49-4, p. 4107" with a date of "1913-02-26". The search term is: "GPO-CRECB-1913-pt4-v49" (include the quotes). This leads to: https://www.govinfo.gov/app/details/GPO-CRECB-1913-pt4-v49 . Select "Document in Context". A list of dates is presented. For "House of Representatives: February 26, 1913", select "PDF" to view the document. Page down (or search for) page 4107. [The direct link.](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-CRECB-1913-pt4-v49/pdf/GPO-CRECB-1913-pt4-v49-14-2.pdf#page=39)

At the end of each session, an index is printed. The PDF "button" for the index appears at the bottom of the "part" that contains the last date of the session. That index can be quite large 300+ MB or nearly 1000 pages. Furthermore, because the pages are smudged and sometimes marked, a PDF reader may not be able to search for items; such as the name of a Representative or the number of a resolution. Persistence may pay off.

Comment: @Rick Smith you are a genius, thank you! That answers my question!

Answer (score -3):

If I needed this bill I would go to my University library and ask. The people there are professionals and helped me several times with hard to find texts. I think that the Library of Congress has all the bills ever considered by the US Congress and any library can get that bill by interlibrary loan.